# How can I preserve border width when scaling an object with Inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape, resize, borders

I want the **borders to stay fixed** in Inkscape when I'm **resizing an object**. I found these buttons in **Inkscape v0.48.3.1**, but they don't seem to work. Is there any other **settings** that I should turn on?

These are the buttons that should control that:

[image]

**EDIT**
The answer below should be valid, but for some reason this doesn't work for me as I mentioned in the question already. It's probably a bug or there's some additional settings which prevent the normal behavior.

Comment: I've run into a similar issue when scaling groups. Sometimes the renderer applies the scale to the stroke too. As a quick fix, ungroup and immediately re-group. This seems to apply the group's scale to the paths and recreates the group with a blank uniform scale.

Comment: It´s not working for me as well. That sucks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've tried under Windows with your version and with the most recent one and it works as usual.

In order to maintain the border stroke while scaling the object, the first button should be **up** (in your screenshot seems to be *down*, i.e. the stroke is scaled with the object):

[image: Maintain the border]

Comment: Well thanks, but that's exactly what I had. I'm on Ubuntu, and on my screenshot it's in hover position. Not sure what's causing this..

Comment: I'm curious now. As soon as possible I will verify on an Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Just tried on an Ubuntu machine and it worked well. I'm sorry, it was not possible test it with v0.48.3.1, the installed version was v0.48.4.9939 and I was too lazy to downgrade it. Have you considered to upgrade your version to the last one?

Comment: Well thanks. I'll mark it as the answer, because probably the problem is in the version. I tried to upgrade Inkscape by following https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ppa. It doesn't seem to to the job both through sources.list and thru PPA. But anyway, I managed to live without that feature :)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, and the suggested solution doesn't work for me as well. I found another way around.

You select the 'Edit path by nodes tool' (F2), and select the path you want to transform. Select all nodes by pressing Ctrl+a. You then press the 'Show transformation handles for selected nodes' button (the four black arrows pointing towards each other).

You can now transform the path without changing the stroke width.

Comment: This should not be the answer T_T but it is.

Answer (score 0):

The button did not work for me either.

I have the problem of changing line width when I group two objects and try to scale them together.

An alternative way to scale "grouped objects" is to combine the paths rather than group them. Then scale as per usual.

Answer (score 0):

At first I tought deactivating the button does not work for me either, but it was just the preview which was wrong. When scaling and still holding the mouse button the border also scaled. But after releasing the mouse button the border went back to its original size.

[image]