# How to change stroke width of image made by drawing in iPad?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, stroke, ipad

I have a drawing using Adobe Ideas app in iPad, then export it to PDF to open it with Inkscape. It is a vector image since I can enlarge it as much as I want. However the width of the stroke too big when I enlarge so I want to reduce it. When I double click on it, the result appears as the picture below and I don't know how to resize it. Do you know how to achieve my purpose? Thank you.

Beside Inkscape, I can use Illustrator.

[image]

---

Here are my [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fc5o2xela0fyx0f/immature.pdf?dl=0) and my screen shot of the top bar:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you double click on a path in Inkscape, you enter in **node editing** mode and you can [edit](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Editing.html) the path.

You can return to **select** mode by clicking the arrow in the toolbar on the left (or by hitting the keyboard shortcut, usually F1):

[image: Inkscape toolbar]

In select mode you can resize or rotate your shape.

You can change the **[stroke attributes](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Attributes-Stroke.html)** using the button on the top toolbar.

[image: Other Inkscape tools]

The behaviour of the stroke **while resizing** depends from the status of the buttons on the top toolbar (see above and give a look [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24736/how-can-i-preserve-border-width-when-scaling-an-object-with-inkscape)).

---

*Postil*

Regarding your file, after the import in Inkscape you see the structure of your image by changing the *Display Mode* to [outline](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/View-Misc.html):

[image: outline mode]

The contour is made by the [difference](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Combining.html) of two closed paths, each eye is a closed path, the smile is a closed path and there is an open path (perhaps a test?):

[image: outline mode explained]

Let's return to Normal mode. Select the object and [ungroup](https://inkscape.org/doc/basic/tutorial-basic.html) it by clicking **Shift-Ctrl-G** until you got a message of no more groups to ungroup.

Select just the "cloud" (the contour of your face) and change [fill and stroke](https://inkscape.org/doc/basic/tutorial-basic.html), e.g. with a blue fill and a black stroke of 5 px:

[image: reveal the shape]

As you see, in this way you have evidence that the "cloud" is not a path with a heavy stroke, but is a composition of an internal and an external path.

In order to have a single path, you must select your "cloud" and [Break Apart](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Editing.html) them with **Shift-Ctrl-K**:

[image: break apart the paths]

Now, **delete** one of the paths (the internal, in my example) and change stroke and fill as desired.

A similar operation should be made on the mouth (you can cut the path and keep an open path). And perhaps to the eyes.

In this way, you can scale the image maintaining the stroke attributes:

[image: final image]

---

*Conclusions*

In my opinion, such an operation (doodle with a tablet, export and import in a [vector graphics editing program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_vector_graphics_editors)) is **possible**, but you need **a bit of work** to adapt the result to your specific needs.

It could be simpler if you have *in advance* an idea of the **desired result**: you can choose the proper tool from the beginning.

Comment: I get the same result that the OP in your linked question met: it doesn't work. I use Win 8.1 and just downloaded Inkscape some days ago.

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1 too, with the latest version of Inkscape. Can you share your SVG file and a screenshot of the top toolbar?

Comment: Since the origin is in PDF type, I'll upload it. Please see my update. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your toolbar the button related to the behaviour of the stroke while resizing seems to be checked. Have you tried to uncheck it?

Comment: Yes, i have tried to check and uncheck it. The result doesn't change, the width of the shape changes (proportionally?) when I enlarge it.

Comment: Ok, in your image the elements are done with two different paths and no stroke (not with a single path with a large stroke). You can proceed by ungroup the elements, divide the path, remove one of the paths, set a proper fill and stroke to the other. No time now to send you an example, perhaps later.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to work on that. If I still can't work it out, I'll inform you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18311/discussion-between-paolo-gibellini-and-ooker).

Comment: very helpful. Thank you. I didn't notice that you had edited your answer. You should ping me to that I could know that.

Comment: Ok, I thought that writing in chat would send the alerts ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Ideas essentially uses the Blob Brush to draw. This means it expands artwork and *nothing* remains as a stroke. Everything becomes a shape.

In Illustrator...

An easy way to reduce the width of a shape, especially in a black and white image, is to add a white stroke to the shape.

Then select the shape and choose `Object > Expand`.

Then click the **Merge** button on the **Pathfinder Panel**

And lastly, select the white shapes and delete them.

Comment: I can't find the `Expand` on the `Object` menu

Comment: I don't really know what to tell you, it's there -- grey if you haven't added a stroke or selected something and black (live) if you have.

Comment: I currently use Inkscape. Are you talking in Illustrator?

Comment: Yes.. I was referring to Illustrator. You tagged this with Illustrator. I should have been more clear.

Comment: When choosing `Object > Expand`, which box should I choose? `Fill` and `Stroke` boxes are available.

Comment: Just leave them both selected and hit OK. The "fill" won't do anything for flat fills.. so it doesn't *really* matter if it's checked or not in this instance. You just need to be certain "stroke" is checked.