# Where is the option for scaling stroke width in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, stroke, borders

When you scale objects in Inkscape, it either scales the stroke with the object, or it leaves the stroke width alone.  I think I've seen a button for it on another post next to "Affect:" but can't find it.

Where is this option actually located?

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I've already looked at that post - it's the one I referred to - and it does not explain where the options are

Comment: @PhilipHartfield: If you cannot find the buttons with those two screenshots, you are likely having a technical issue, which would be off-topic here.

Comment: How is that off topic? My inkscape version is most likely just different.

Comment: According to just the title of the question, this would be an answer for many visitors: **If you're looking for the docked dialog on the right side of the screen. Open with: Object menu > Fill and Stroke. (CTRL+Shift+F)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting appears at two places:

#### 1. In the toolbar (see [related question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24736/how-can-i-preserve-border-width-when-scaling-an-object-with-inkscape))

- Make sure that the toolbar is shown (`View > Show/Hide > Tool Controls Bar`).
- Select the mouse tool (<kbd>F1</kbd>).
- In the toolbar, click the icon for scaling strokes.

[image: toolbar]

#### 2. In the preferences dialog

- Open the preferences dialog (`Edit > Preferences...` or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>)
- Go to `Behaviour > Transforms`
- Select `Scale Stroke width`

[image: Preferences]