# Is there a way to resize a vector such that one of its dimensions is equal to a desired size in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to create a circuit schematic using Inkscape. I've created several vector images of components and am trying to connect them up into a circuit. These are two of them, for instance:

[image]

I'm having trouble getting their endpoints to be a consistent size so that I can connect them with a black rectangle of the same width. I've tried using grids, but to no success. Is there a way to, say, automatically resize an object (while preserving aspect ratio) such that a specified dimension equals a desired value (in this case the specified dimension is the width of one of the connection points)? Or, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure there is a good simple solution for this, so I shall offer my clumsy one and one workaround. **Clumsy method first**:

1. Using the path/node edit tool (F2 by default) you can select the individual nodes that represent the corners of interest on one shape and read their x/y coordinates.
2. Repeat 1. for the other shape.
3. You can then calculate the dimension for each specified object and their ratio.
4. Using *Object > Transform* (or shift+ctrl+M by default) menu, you can then scale one of the obects by that ratio (with the option *Scale proportionally* ticked).

I would not want to do this for more than one or two shapes.

**The reasonable workaround**:
If you can retrace the shapes in strokes with set widths, you can then scale them without scaling the stroke ([How can I preserve border width when scaling an object with Inkscape?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/24736/how-can-i-preserve-border-width-when-scaling-an-object-with-inkscape)), so you won't have the issue to begin with, and all lines will be nice and consistent.

**One more option**: This may not suit your needs, but for the sake of completeness – use specialized software designed for drawing schemes and circuitry. Haven't used any myself, but there are some free options available.

Comment: I used the workaround method, which works great.

Answer (score 0):

(another slightly clumsy method, alternative scenario)

If your shapes were closed paths with black fill and no stroke (which you can accomplish by `Path > Stroke to Path`), you could connect them like this:

1. Make sure that cusp node snapping is checked.

[image]

2. Drag the object and snap one of the corners to its counterpart.

[image]

3. Click on the object once to see its rotation center, make sure that rotation center snapping is checked.

[image]

4. Drag and snap the rotation center to the same corner you snapped in step 2.

[image]

5. Make sure the lock button is checked and scale the object while holding Shift (=scale around rotation center) until the other corner snaps to its counterpart. It's best to scale by dragging the objest's corner that is furthest from the rotation center.

[image]