# How to frame text like the logo design of the 1968 olympic games in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, line-art

I want to have a header on a cover design of a cover I am making, that looks like the logo below. The problem arises when I want a lot of these outer lines. My method so far is to make each line individually but that would be a lot of work.
I am making these outlines by taking the next inner line and scaling it so that the distance and curvature match up. Then I reduce the width of the new line, which increased because of the scaling I just did.
So my question is, if there is some general and more consistent method to surround any shape with equally thick lines with equal distance to each other.
[image: Logo of the 1968 Olympic games]

Comment: BTW you can [turn off line width scaling](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/24736/15344).  That would save a few steps

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That was most likely drawn entirely by hand. The advent of using computers in graphic design didn't really happen until the late 1980s.

But yes, something similar can be done in Inkscape by applying Offset path effects to duplicates repeatedly

For example

[image]

Comment: I'd be curious to see how this would work in Illustrator.

Comment: I like the note in your first paragraph. In particular, it's easy to forget today that "by hand" doesn't necessarily imply *free*-hand. A compass and a ruler probably saw a lot of use by whoever drew that original logo. (Conveniently, and probably not coincidentally, all the letter shapes in the logo are made up of straight lines and circle arcs, and thus the surrounding outlines are also composed of concentric circle arcs and parallel straight line segments.)

Comment: @ArashHowaida mostly exactky the same way

Comment: @IlmariKaronen sure. You can buy tape that is thin and flexible it comes in different widths and that can be laid down next to your line for a consistent offset for complex shapes.

Comment: The GCode tools area fill extension (first tab) can create multiple offsets of the same distance automatically, which could save a lot of time here. It's not perfect, but will save a lot of work.
  Screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/A2urF3W

Comment: @Moini - yeah, that looks like it could be very useful.