# How can I make concentric text in inskscape?

Tags: inkscape, outline

I essentially want to outline my text multiple times. Something like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Apply path offset repeatedly.

Comment: See this closely related question and answer: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/154015/89608

Comment: @jooja I'm using a thick font, so doing so just makes one outline thicker and thicker until it becomes a blob

Comment: wait nvm, I think I figured it out